# How to translate: university application sentences

Tags: meaning, word-choice, translation

I would need to know whether the following is correct:

> I applied for study of mathematics and physics.

or do I need to say it like that:

> I applied for admission to university to study mathematics and
>   physics.

Is the first enough to express the meaning of the other sentence?
Thanks

Comment: Native speakers wouldn't normally say *"I applied **for** study of mathematics and physics"* - they'd invariably use "***to***". Other than that, you don't necessarily need to include *"for admission"* or *"to university"*.

Comment: If you follow @FumbleFingers' good advice and replace "*for*" with "*to*", be sure to also take out the "*of*" after "*study*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say, "I applied to study mathematics and physics" — you don't necessarily need to mention the university unless you want to differentiate between university,  college etc.

Comment: I can't say I agree with the idea that "applied for" somehow implies "scholarship" (which I take it you mean in the "financial support" sense). To my mind, all it implies is the possibility that you might be rejected - but even that isn't a definite. Someone who knows they're going to get straight A's can still say they've **applied** to three universities, with pretty much 100% certainty that they'll be accepted by all three. The "bare" meaning is simply that you've formally asked to be accepted for something.

Comment: Agreed - have removed the second part of my answer.